# How do I KMS decrypt the password in the application.properties first before being used in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-kms

my first time using AWS and spring boot together.

I have my db credentials set up in application.properties.

But I still need to KMS decrypt the password.

How do I do that in spring boot framework?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should include the ***"zalando/spring-cloud-config-aws-kms"*** dependancy to your project, for more details about the project check this link: *"https://github.com/zalando/spring-cloud-config-aws-kms"*
You should be careful about the choice of versions, for example if you are using ***Spring Cloud Greenwich + Spring Boot 2.1*** the ***zalando*** dependency version should be **4.1**

Now suppose your spring-boot project is a maven project, then you should have something like this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-aws-kms</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Second, your encrypted password value in the application.properties should begin with `{cipher}`, example (the cipher shown below is not a valid one):

```
DataBase.Password = {cipher}UmjDPAmJr78ypSphQycO9DAQECAHgC4i08YQPW
```

Finally, because you have the ***spring-cloud-config-aws-kms*** in your project classPath you have only to inject the value of your encrypted password in your classes when needed via the `@Value` annotaion, as an example:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Example {
    //reads the encrypted password, decrypts it 
    // and injects it in the field DataBasePassword 
    @Value("${DataBase.Password}")
    private String DataBasePassword;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String decryptPassword() {
        return DataBasePassword;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }
}
```

Launch this Spring-Boot application, open a browser and type the url *"http://localhost:8080/"* to see the result.
This answer is inspired from this project *"https://github.com/kinow/spring-boot-aws-kms-configuration"*. Hope that will be helpful :)